# Returning an attribute of a node based on specific constraints from another node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to query the following:

**List the Names of students who have at least one A in courses they are enrolled in. (Do not consider A- as an A.)**

[Image of the schema for my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q1Lt.png)

I am using the following query:

```
    MATCH (studentPerson)<-[:S2P]-(:Student)-[:Taking]->(:Offering)-
    [:Covers]->(studentCourse)

    WHERE studentCourse.Grade = "A"
    RETURN studentPerson.Name as student
```

But each time I run it, I keep getting "(no changes, no records)".
I also tried using `EXISTS(studentCourse.Grade = "A")` to no avail.

When the records were added to the database, they were added from a file like so:

```
    match (a:Student), (b:Offering) where a.ID = 419180204 and b.ID = 15 
    create (a) - [r:Taking{EnrollmentID:'Enrollment306',Grade: 'A-'}]-> (b) 
    WITH count(*) as dummy

    match (a:Student), (b:Offering) where a.ID = 449976666 and b.ID = 15 
    create (a) - [r:Taking{EnrollmentID:'Enrollment307',Grade: 'C+'}]-> (b) 
    WITH count(*) as dummy

    match (a:Student), (b:Offering) where a.ID = 477453864 and b.ID = 15 
    create (a) - [r:Taking{EnrollmentID:'Enrollment308',Grade: 'A'}]-> (b) 
    WITH count(*) as dummy

    match (a:Student), (b:Offering) where a.ID = 495490053 and b.ID = 15 
    create (a) - [r:Taking{EnrollmentID:'Enrollment309',Grade: 'A-'}]-> (b)
```

Is it possible that due to the entities being added into the relationship ("r:Taking") that the Offering node does not even have grades?
I'm brand new at `neo4j` and trying my best, but this stuff is so confusing to me so far.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow and the world of Neo4j/Cypher! I think the problem is that `Grade` is a property of the `:Taking` relationship. So, in your query, add a variable to that relationship type, e.g. `(:Student)-[t:Taking]->(:Offering)` and use `t.Grade = 'A'` for filtering.

Comment: that makes soooo much more sense now. Thanks you so much @GaborSzarnyas !

Comment: You're welcome. Based on the comment, I created an answer, please accept it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Grade` is a property of the `:Taking` relationship. So, in your query, add a variable to that relationship type, e.g. `(:Student)-[t:Taking]->(:Offering)` and use `t.Grade = 'A'` for filtering:

```
MATCH (studentPerson)<-[:S2P]-(:Student)-[t:Taking]->(:Offering)-
  [:Covers]->(studentCourse)
WHERE t.Grade = `A`
RETURN studentPerson.Name as student
```